# How to use JAR in code? Easy at Android Studio but it doesn't work in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea, jar

In `Android Studio` I've created a dummy project to testing package [Klaxon](https://github.com/cbeust/klaxon/blob/master/README.md), that handles `JSON`. So I put the below code inside `onCreate` do change the text of `creatorButton` button.

```
class Product(val name: String)  // Kotlin, but could be Java
val product = Product("HDD")
val result = Klaxon().toJsonString(product)   
creatorButton.text = result
```

`Klaxon` is in `jcenter` repository. So in `Build.Gradle` module file, I've added in `dependency` group:

```
implementation 'com.beust:klaxon:5.0.1'
```

When I've run the app in my Android cell phone, the button display the label

```
{"Name":"HDD"}
```

After, I want to test `Klaxon` in depth on `IntelliJ IDEA` so I don't need emulate or run in cell phone all the times that I want to test something.

So I've created a empty `Kotlin` project with `Gradle`.

```
fun main() {
    class Product(val name: String)
    val product = Product("HDD")
    val result = Klaxon().toJsonString(product)  // Error
    println(result)
}
```

I follow the tips in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project) and add the `JAR` library in Project Structure (It doesn't work) or add the JAR library in `libs` folder and run "Add as Library"(it did not work either)

PS: I've tried to edit the dependencies in `Gradle.build`, but it not accept the same Android Studio syntax.

How can I do to solve this mistery?
No matter what I do, it always gives error on the line with `Klaxon` call()

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library

Paulo, please take a look at the above question/answer. Using `files` for a single jar or `filetree` for multiple jars in a path should help you.

Comment: I try to use all this statements in the gradle.build. Nothing works. However, I have discovered a solution and will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a different trick, since no attempt to edit `Gradle`in `IntelliJ IDEA` using sames commands as I do in `Android Studio` has worked inside `dependencies` group: I try to use `implementation` with a `jcenter` string, with `files` or `filetree` command (as explained in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies))

First, I've closed the `Kotlin` project with `Gradle`.

Then I've created a new `Kotlin` project without include `Gradle` (it's the most important step), copy all source code and add the JAR file in the same way proposed in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project) question.

So I check if in `File / Settings/ Editor / General / Auto Import`, the option `Insert Import on Paste` is `all`, and `Add unambiguous import on the fly` is `on`.

Finally when I use the function `Klaxon()`, `Intellij IDEA`  asks about the missing import and I've confirmed with `Alt+Enter`.

And the source code receives the line

```
import com.beust.klaxon.Klaxon
```

Now my Kotlin code works as a charm

By the way, if one sees the `External Library` in the project tree (left side), one child node is `klaxon.5.0.5.jar` that is my library. It derives to `com.beust.klaxon` the open to the class names.